# Input field going to page on other buttons has clicked not on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

user named vittore helped me to  show first 5 li of the ul and change page with next prev buttons perfectly. prorblem is there is a input field aswell, works good its goes to entered page number but not on submit it goes on next or prev button click. i tried changing 'blur'  with 'submit' or 'keydown' but not working. i wonder if we can make it go to page number on hiting enter or just typing number

```
<button id="prev" >prev</button>
<input id="page"  value="0" />
<button id="more" >next</button>


<script>
var pageSize = 5
 , ul = $('#asd')
 , pages = Math.floor(ul.find('li').length / pageSize)
 , page = 0
 , currentPage = function (i) {
     return page*pageSize <= i && i < (page + 1) * pageSize 
 }

 ul.on('pageChanged.pager', function( e ) {
  ul.find('li').hide().filter(currentPage).show();

})

$('#prev').on('click.pager', function(e) {
    page = Math.max(0, --page)
    $('#page').val(page)
    ul.trigger('pageChanged.pager')
})

$('#more').on('click.pager', function(e) {
   page = Math.min(pages, ++page)
   $('#page').val(page)
   ul.trigger('pageChanged.pager')     
})

$('#page').on('blur.pager', function(e) {
  page = Math.max(0, Math.min(pages, +$(this).val()-1))

  ul.trigger('pageChanged.pager')  
})

ul.trigger('pageChanged.pager')
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/uXn2p/104/ here. but i changed 'page = Math.max(0, Math.min(pages, +$(this).val()-1))' added -1 to make it go to right page but i gues it will be ok to remove when input  goes to page directly. when you click on next  input goes to entered number + 1 from next button.

Comment: change `blur` to `change`

Comment: Any results on changing to `change` event?

Comment: It works now. sorry for delay on comment. Thank you so much for help.

Comment: I have moved our discussion into answer. Please accept it as a correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In accordance to your fiddle you just need to change 'blur' to 'change' event.
You should change this (**blur**) event:

```
$('#page').on('blur.pager', function(e) {
  page = Math.max(0, Math.min(pages, +$(this).val()-1))
  ul.trigger('pageChanged.pager')  
})
```

To this (**change**) event:

```
$('#page').on('change.pager', function(e) {
  page = Math.max(0, Math.min(pages, +$(this).val()-1))

  ul.trigger('pageChanged.pager')  
})
```